# cannot read property 'access_token" of undefined

Tags: facebook, api, express

I'm using Auth0 and trying to get AccessToken. But I faced to difficult problem.
how can I solve this problem?
I've got an error like this:

```
E:\sample projects\Building-API\movieanalyst-website\server.js:27
      if(req.body.access_token){
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined
    at E:\sample projects\Building-API\movieanalyst-website\server.js:27:18
    at Request.callback (E:\sample projects\Building-API\movieanalyst-website\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:688:3)
    at E:\sample projects\Building-API\movieanalyst-website\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:883:18
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\sample projects\Building-API\movieanalyst-website\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\parsers\json.js:16:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! movieanalyst-website@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the movieanalyst-website@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the movieanalyst-website package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs movieanalyst-website
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls movieanalyst-website
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Assassin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-24T11_28_24_478Z-debug.log
```

According to the error, code is this

```
function getAccessToken(req, res, next) {
  request
    .post('https://shinji-sakai.auth0.com/oauth/token')
    .send(authData)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if(req.body.access_token){
        req.access_token = res.body.access_token;
        next();
      } else {
        res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
      }
    })
}
```

plz, give me the way to solve this problem.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you researched what the error message means? What basic debugging steps have you undertaken so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `body` property from your `req` request is undefined. You should check you request to see if you are sending the correct data. Maybe you can use postman or another RESTful API to test.

Also you can change your code to check the `body` property first, like this (but I think that your problem is with the actual request):

```
function getAccessToken(req, res, next) {
  request
    .post('https://shinji-sakai.auth0.com/oauth/token')
    .send(authData)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if(req.body && req.body.access_token) {
        req.access_token = res.body.access_token;
        next();
      } else {
        res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
and then `TypeError: res.send is not a function`
what's this?

Comment: It means that `res.send` is not a function, so it cannot be called like this: `res.send(401, 'unauthorized')`. The `res` object is also probably `undefined` or some other type that doesn't have the `send` function. Check how you are calling the `getAccessToken` function and what are you sending to it.

Comment: Shinji, I would love to know what you did to solve problem. I have same exact problem and have been trying and cant get auth0 to return auth_token. Postman shows that request is being access denied. no authorization.